Why Angular build process detects so many file changes?
I am working on my Angular project while it's built for development. I edit one file and save, but the terminal tells me that it detected modifications in all files in the project.

This seems to cause a longer build process than I would expect, i.e. my build from the above screenshot finishes in 4 minutes. I would expect a faster (incremental?) build if I edit only one or two lines in a single file.
I use VS Code as my editor. I turned off Auto Save in VS Code. I save using Save (Ctrl+S), not Save All (Ctrl+K S).
I use Angular version ^17.0.8.
I use the ng build command to build my app:
./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build craft-app -c=development

My development configuration uses "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application", and "watch": true:
    "projects": {
      "craft-app": {
        "architect": {
          "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
            "configurations": {
              "development": {
                "verbose": true,
                "watch": true,
                "outputPath": "../dist/development/craft-app",
                "optimization": false,
                "outputHashing": "none",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "namedChunks": true,
                "aot": false,
                "extractLicenses": false,
                "statsJson": false,
                "progress": true
              }
            }

I've checked a few other questions/answers, including How do I build with watch enabled using angular-cli?, but most focus on the build being slow. My question here is about how it detects so many changes.
